# Yii2 Update Action JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, yii2

I created a jquery to show a modal window when creating new reservation, and it worked fine.
But I'm having some trouble defining the url for the update action (it has dynamic url according to id). And I'm **defining the url wrong** in this part:

```
$.get('reservation/update',{'id'}, function(data)
```

Here is **main.js**:

```
$(function() {

$(document).on('click','.fc-day',function(){
var date= $(this).attr('data-date');
$.get('?r=reservation/create',{'date':date}, function(data)
{
    $('#modal').modal('show')
      .find('#modalContent')
      .html(data);
    });     
});

$(document).on('click','.fc-day-grid-event',function(){

    $.get('reservation/update',{'id'}, function(data)
    {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
          .find('#modalContent')
          .html(data);
        });     
    });

$('#modalButton').click(function(){

$('#modal').modal('show')
.find('#modalContent')
.load($(this).attr('value'));   });  });
```

Here is **ActionUpdate** in the ReservationController:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Reservation Index.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

$this->title = 'Reservations';
 $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="reservation-index">

<h2> &nbsp;<?=  Html::encode($this->title) ?></h2>

<br>
<?php   
Modal::begin([
'header'=>'reservation',
'id'=>'modal',
'size'=>'modal-lg',  
]);

echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end(); 
?>

<?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
    'events'=> $events,)); ?>

</div>
```

So how should I parse the id parameter from model to the URL?

Comment: try to put id the same way as you did it for date. that is try putting it in `data-id` attr of element having class `fc-day-grid-event` and then fetch it in click event

Answer (score 1):

Get Your id variable of Javascript  as:-

```
$(document).on('click','.fc-day-grid-event',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.get('reservation/update',{id : id}, function(data)
    {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
          .find('#modalContent')
          .html(data);
        });     
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. No runtime errors are given, and other scripts work. But this script doesn't.